# Windows 10 run powershell script as admin automatically on power up

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator

I need to run a powershell script, as admin, anytime the computer is restarted. We don't normally have access to the admin account (so we can't just regularly punch in the admin credentials), but the admin will work with us to see if we can add it as a....admin startup task? group policy?

Is there a way to accomplish this? Obviously the admin will sign in initially to set this up, but we need it to run as admin without having to ask the user for the admin credentials every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the PowerShell script via the Task Scheduler,

Create the appropriate task, set it to run with highest privileges,
and specify the trigger as At startup.

Many sources are available on the subject. A random one is
[How to create an automated task using Task Scheduler on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).